# How do you load custom UITableViewCells from Xib files in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi i am very beginner in iOS and in my `UITableView` I am loading `UITableViewCell` from Xib using below code but UIFields are not fitting perfectly as like my below screen please help me why fields are not fitting perfectly?

### my code:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    DetailsTableViewCell *cell = (DetailsTableViewCell *)[MaintableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetailsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 100;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [Bg colorWithHexString:@"FFB848"];
    UIView * whiteRoundedView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, self.view.frame.size.width, 70)];
    whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = [Bg colorWithHexString:@"EF4836"].CGColor;
    whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, -1);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:whiteRoundedView];
    [cell.contentView sendSubviewToBack:whiteRoundedView];
}
```

[image]

Comment: increase the cell height and try ...

Comment: did you use expand and collapse tableview ?

Comment: yes i have used in my previouse apps

Comment: @abiRam your current tableview is using a expand and collapse tableview or its just normal tableview

Comment: i increase cell height no use

Comment: did you increase the tableview ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99087/discussion-between-abhiram-and-kishore-kumar).

Comment: Comment this method & tell the result. -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

Comment: yes if i comment that method then working perfectly but i nedd to maintain gap between each cell and that's why i must use that method

Comment: please check your tableview cell height and your custom cell height if both height are not same then change your tableview cell height same as custom cell height.

Comment: @AbhiRam: Whats the red colored view? Is is the custom background UIView added to cell?

Answer (score 1):

You can design the custom cell as per your requirements with ur required edge insets ,in this way

[image]

All cells will be of same size hence the required gap will be maintained easily.

Register your nib and use your custom cell as

```
[tableName registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"customCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"customCell"];
```

Hope it helps.. happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add this method to use a background view

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
```

You can add a `UIView` to your nib file from the interface builder and to round the corners you can create a `IBOutlet` property for that `UIView` and then inside your `DetailsTableViewCell.m` file inside the below method, do your corder round implementation.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {  
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];  
    //your custom initialization code  
    return self;  
}
```

Comment: Create a UIView inside that DetailsTableViewCell.xib cell & place it in background

Comment: sorry,if you don't mind i will send my sample project can you see what is mistack there please? it just 2 mins for your's

Comment: Right now I don't have a Mac with me. So it'll take about 8 hours to fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "LoadMoreTableViewCell.h"
```

Register custom nib.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([LoadMoreTableViewCell class])
                                               bundle:nil]
                               forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([LoadMoreTableViewCell class])];
}
```

Return the custom cell from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self loadMoreTableViewCellForTableView:tableView indexPath:indexPath];
}

- (LoadMoreTableViewCell *)loadMoreTableViewCellForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    LoadMoreTableViewCell *cell =  (LoadMoreTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([LoadMoreTableViewCell class])];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
```